# sorting file based on filenames

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to sort some files (not the content inside) based on file names

I already tried ls -v but that only sort the files based on the numbers
I am trying to sort for example

```
abc.adult.fasta
abc.1.1.fasta
abc.14.3.fasta
abc.3.2.fasta
```

the numbers are the age of the animal and therefore the adult should be in the last.

```
ls -v
```

The result should first be based on the actual numerical value they have then based on the alphabetical order. as list

```
abc.1.1.fasta
abc.3.2.fasta
abc.14.3.fasta
abc.adult.fasta
```

Comment: That's ALMOST possible ... sort uses ASCII, and when you have both numerical and character values in a column characters come first.  `sort -t. -k2,2n`

Comment: but if I use sort directly, it will sort the content inside the files right. I only want to list the files in order based on the filename but not the content inside the files

Comment: So pipe the output of `ls` into `sort` ...

Answer (score 1):

With a zero in front of one digit numbers, sorting is easy.
This can be done with sed.

```
ls | sed -E 's/\.([0-9])\./\.0\1\./g' | sort | sed -E 's/\.0([0-9])\./\.\1\./g'
```

The first sed adds a zero in front of one-digit numbers, while the second removes it.

Answer (score 0):

custom sorting with key replacement

```
$ ls -1 | sed 's/\.adult\./.99./' | sort -V | sed 's/\.99\./.adult./'

abc.1.1.fasta
abc.3.2.fasta
abc.14.3.fasta
abc.adult.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ls and sort command via pipe. 
Eg.
ls -l | sort -t. -k2,2n